# Project Euler #5 (Smallest multiple) in Swift

Tags: programming-challenge, mathematics, swift

I found this one a little bit easier than the previous problems, but I was already familiar with the GCD/LCM formulas.

```
import Foundation

func printTimeElapsedWhenRunningCode(title:String, operation:()->()) {
    let startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    operation()
    let timeElapsed = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime
    println("Time elapsed for \(title): \(timeElapsed) s")
}

func greatestCommonDenominator(a: Int, b: Int) -> Int {
    return b == 0 ? a : greatestCommonDenominator(b, a % b)
}

func leastCommonMultiple(a: Int, b: Int) -> Int {
    return a * (b / greatestCommonDenominator(a, b))
}

func leastCommonMultiple(input: [Int]) -> Int {
    var result: Int = input[0]
    for value in input {
        result = leastCommonMultiple(result, value)
    }
    return result
}

func solution5() {
    let firstTwentyInts: [Int] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
    let answer: Int = leastCommonMultiple(firstTwentyInts)

    println(String(answer))
}

printTimeElapsedWhenRunningCode("Least Common Multiple", solution5)
```

And for the record, I know that `solution5()` is ugly as a function, but for the purposes of this review, you should think of that more like you might think of `main` in another programming language.  Ultimately, I've only packaged those lines of code into a function so I can throw it in `printTimeElapsedWhenRunningCode()` which is a nice way to time my solutions.

This particular solution consistently runs in under 0.001 seconds (some times as low as 0.0004 seconds) for me.

Comment: Minor suggestion: `let firstTwentyInts = [Int](1 ... 20)`.

Comment: I was wondering if there was an easier way, but couldn't easily find it.

Answer (score 1):

In general, I like it; nice solution. Functions are well separated and I understood what it was doing right away, just from the function names.

You can get rid of one of your `leastCommonMultiple` functions (and make it more Swifty I think) by passing it a `Range` instead of an `Array` and by using `reduce()`:

```
func greatestCommonDenominator(a: Int, b: Int) -> Int {
    return b == 0 ? a : greatestCommonDenominator(b, a % b)
}

func leastCommonMultiple(range: Range<Int>) -> Int {
    return reduce(range, 1) { (a, b) in a * (b / greatestCommonDenominator(a, b)) }
}

func solution5() {
    let answer = leastCommonMultiple(1...20)
    println(answer)
}
```

That change also seems to speed it up significantly. On my machine it changed the average run time from 0.0001 seconds to 0.00002 seconds; I believe that's simply from not having to create the Array though.